# Create one split screen video, separate audio streams and a thumbnail from the resultant split screen video - all in one pass

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, conversion, transcoding

I'm using ffmpeg to create several single splitscreen videos out of 2 separate videos. The 2 videos have audio so I want to extract the 2 video's audio streams as 2 separate mp3s and also create a thumbnail out of the finished splitscreen video. Is it possible to do these 3 actions in one pass?

Here is the code I'd use to create the splitscreen video:

`ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov  -filter_complex "[0]scale=640x360[v0];[1]scale=640x360[v1];[v0][v1] xstack=inputs=2:layout=0_0|w0_0|[v]" -map "[v]" -an output.mp4`

Here is the code I'd use to create the thumbnail of the resultant splitscreen video:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vframes 1  OUTPUT.jpg`

Here is the code I'd use to create one mp3

`ffmpeg -i input0.mov output0.mp3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -filter_complex "[0]scale=640x360[v0];[1]scale=640x360[v1];[v0][v1]hstack,split[video][image]" -map "[video]" output.mp4 -map 0:a audio0.mp3 -map 1:a audio1.mp3 -map "[image]" -frames:v 1 image.jpg
```

For a 4 videos into a 2x2 layout:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -i input2.mov -i input3.mov -filter_complex "[0]scale=640x360[v0];[1]scale=640x360[v1];[2]scale=640x360[v2];[3]scale=640x360[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0,split[video][image]" -map "[video]" output.mp4 -map 0:a audio0.mp3 -map 1:a audio1.mp3 -map 2:a audio2.mp3 -map 3:a audio3.mp3 -map "[image]" -frames:v 1 image.jpg
```

Comment: Your answer works for the split screen video and 2 separate mp3s if I exclude:
"image.jpg"  at the end  

Unfortunately if I add "image.jpg" it makes the video and audio about 1 frame long and doesn't create a thumbnail of the finished resultant splitscreen video, just input1.mov.  
Any ideas?

Comment: @BenHardy See updated answer. Wasn't able to test the first iteration and I forgot a few things.

Comment: This works perfectly. Could this code be adapted for 4 videos? </>

Comment: @BenHardy See updated answer.